# How to rotate a bullet image in toggled unordered list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, slidetoggle

Ok, I have totally retooled my approach (thank you superUntitled) and am making progress...  I have an unordered list that users can toggle and my only remaining issue is that when I expand some items, and then click "Show All Cities" not all of the arrows go in the same direction.  All the arrows change, including the ones on the list items already expanded.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Here's my new Javascript:

```
   $("#Names .airports").hide();
   $("#Names .close").hide();

   $('#Expand').click(function(){
        $('h2').children(".close").toggle();
        $('h2').children(".arrow-down").toggle();
           if($(this).text() == 'Hide All Cities')
           {
               $(this).text('Show All Cities');
               $('#Names .airports').slideUp('fast');
           }
           else
           {
               $(this).text('Hide All Cities');
               $('#Names .airports').slideDown('fast');
           }
           });

    $("#Names h2").addClass("state").click(function() {  
    $(this).parent().children(".airports").slideToggle('fast')
    $(this).children(".close").toggle();
    $(this).children(".arrow-down").toggle();
```

Here's the fiddle illustrating the remaining problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/d3pxx8ds/127/

Thanks in advance

---

Here's my old JavaScript (reference only now):

```
    $(function() {
$('li.state').prepend('<img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2227/picol/32/arrow_sans_up_32.png" class="arrow"/>');});
    $('.stateNames ul').hide();
    $('.stateNames li').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('ul').toggle(); 
        var value = 0
        $(".arrow").rotate({ 
            bind: 
            { 
                click: function(){
                   value +=180;
                $(this).rotate(value)
                }
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: you are trying to bind a click handler inside a click handler and that click handler requires clicking directly on the arrow. Change the class and use css, no need for a plugin for this

Comment: Hi charliefl, I had initially had the arrow as a list-style-image within css, but couldn't figure out how to get it to rotate, can you advise what css command I should use?  Thanks

Comment: fairly easy to google css rotate

Comment: @charlietfl, I took your advice and removed the plug-in and retooled the javascript, but have one remaining issue - could you please take a look? thanks

Comment: you shouldn't completely rewrite the question...now the answers have no bearing on what was originally asked. Instead roll back the question to original state and start a new question. You can link back to this one if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

All i did was replace the order, i moved the .rotate to happen before the .toggle functions this would read the rotate first and subsequently do the toggle function thus setting the variable to 180 instead of waiting for the toggle to start, not allowing the variable to be set

```
$(function() {
    $('li.state').prepend('<img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2227/picol/32/arrow_sans_up_32.png" class="arrow"/>');
});
$('.stateNames ul').hide();

var value = 0

$(".arrow").rotate({
    bind : {
        click : function() {
            value += 180;
            $(this).rotate(value)
        }
    }
});

$('.stateNames li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();

});
```

Comment: Thanks morogoyo, that does make them work independently.  However, if I expand the first item and then try to expand the second, the arrow on the second item doesn't turn right away.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?  Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d3pxx8ds/20/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function() {
    $('li.state').prepend('<img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2227/picol/32/arrow_sans_up_32.png" class="arrow"/>');
});

$('.stateNames ul').hide();

var value = 0
$(".arrow").rotate({ 
    bind: 
     { 
        click: function(){

            value +=180;
        $(this).rotate(value)
        if (value==180){
            value=360;
        }
            else{
              value=180;
            }
        }
     } 
}); 

$('.stateNames li').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find('ul').toggle(); 
});
```

I added the if statement  and it works for one full go around but on the next toggle the arrow doesn't rotate hope that helps for now i will keep looking in to it